# i have to use the argument passed in flask route inside the html pages.. how to do it?

Tags: python, jinja2

Python file:

```
@app.route('/home/<argument>')
def home_page(argument):
    return render_template('home.html', keys=argument)
```

HTML file:

```
<!-- inside the url http://127.0.0.1:5000/home/age -->
{{ if argument == "age" }}
    <p>Age 50</p>
{{ else }}
    <p>Invalid</p>
{{ endif }}
```

This results in the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'argument'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think syntax for if else in jinja2 is wrong it should be like this:

```
@app.route('/home/<argument>')
def home_page(argument):
    return render_template('home.html', argument=argument)
```

Code:

```
{% if argument == "age" %}
   <p>Age 50</p>
{% else %}
   <p>Invalid</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The first and last curly bracket is too much. Without them the syntax is correct. See [the docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if).

Comment: yes, I updated the answer that was by mistake

Comment: yeah my syntax is wrong but even if i give "age" only the else part run

Comment: after correcting the syntax only else part work even if i am in the url http://127.0.0.1:5000/home/age .. because it dont know what is argument. plz help with this

Comment: **def home_page(argument):
    return render_template('home.html', argument=argument)** change key to argument as in html your using argument.

Answer (score 1):

First, modify your view function, remember to put a slash after the dynamic URL variable `/home/<argument>/`

```py
@app.route('/home/<argument>/')
def hello_world(argument):
    return render_template('home.html', keys=argument)
```

And, there in the view function, you have passed the `argument` data in the `keys` variable. So, call the `keys` in your `home.html` file with the correct syntax.

```html
{% if keys == "age" %}
    <p>Age 50</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Invalid</p>
{% endif %}
```

This will solve your problem. Happy coding

Comment: Pleasure @MuthuVijay . 
Mark and accept this answer, so others can easily find this answer helpful.